# javascript iframe link referrer

Tags: javascript, http, iframe, referrer

A page loads another domain in an iframe. If javascript inside the iframe clicks on a link in the iframe which domain will the referrer be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Referer will be the page on which the link is clicked. In your case, it will be domain that is opened in iframe.

Answer (score 3):

Unless it's IE6 - then it's the original page - strange? Ohh yes

Answer (score -1):

It will obviously refer to the new domain.