# What is the HTTP Referer if the link is clicked in an <iframe>?

Tags: html, http, iframe, http-referer

Suppose I have a webpage located at http://www.website.com with an `<iframe>` in it. Like this:

```
<html>
 <head>...</head>
 <body>
  ...
  <iframe src="http://www.washington.edu">
  ...
 </body>
</html>
```

Now suppose someone goes to www.website.com and clicks a link in the iframe itself (this link is located on www.washington.edu website).

My question is what is the HTTP Referer in this case?

Is it http://www.website.com (the page hosting iframe) or is it http://www.washington.edu (the page in which the link was clicked)?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324202/javascript-iframe-link-referrer. Interestingly, however, IE6 will always report the iframe's parent page as the referrer.

Comment: Good that IE6 is no longer supported.

Comment: Try working for a large public sector organization or some major blue chips in the UK :-(

Comment: Oh yes, and switching privacy modes on in browsers will turn this feature off entirely.

Comment: Please consider switching the approval to my answer, @bodacydo. See the rationale in the discussion below muskratt's answer's below.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It depends on the browser.

Firefox and Safari will report the referrer as http://www.website.com while some versions of Internet Explorer will show http://www.washington.edu as the referrer.

UPDATE 2015-04: Testing latest versions of above mentioned, all of them would return http://www.washington.edu

Comment: Sir, I think you mean the other way around. I am certain. I accepted your answer anyway. Thanks.

Comment: @GregDubicki I'm not sure that should be a 3rd party edit, since it's, in effect, completely reversing what the OP's answer was saying. I think it is better to remain as a comment. Thus I rejected your edit suggestion. If you disagree, feel free to ask about it on Meta SO!

Comment: Sorry, I think that I may have overedited, because the "UPDATE" part is correct now, but the sentence before is incorrect. Please compare it with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324202/javascript-iframe-link-referrer and http://stackoverflow.com/a/2324226/2693875 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/2822853/2693875.

Comment: Ok @TylerH : http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303023/what-to-do-with-a-question-that-is-incorrect-unless-you-follow-its-comments

Comment: I've added my own answer, as suggested in Meta. It shoud be correct and I have additionally added some of my newest findings on this subject.

Comment: What if the iframe doesn't have any src? Then the referrer would be the url of that iframe's parent object, or no referrer header at all?

Answer (score 8):

## Current browsers

As of August 2015 all the major browsers (Safari, Chrome, Firefox) *should* set the `Referer` HTTP header to http://www.washington.edu in this case.

*But* I encourage you to test how specific browsers versions behave in specific cases if your application depends on `Referer` value heavily.

I write this because for example I have found out that Safari 8 currently makes requests with incorrect `Referer` for JavaScript loaded in iframes, probably if this JavaScript have previously been requested with a different `Referer`. This is a bug that's similar to [this particular one](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=344335) that was closed in Chromium only in 2014. (I have already reported it to Apple, btw.)

## Old browsers

Historically [Internet Explorer 6 showed different behaviour than described above](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200812/referrers_in_iframes.html) - it would set the `Referer` HTTP header to http://www.website.com.