# If an HTTP request is sent from an iframe, where does the iframed site see the request from?

Tags: html, security, http, iframe

Suppose I make a webpage that includes

```
<iframe src="http://google.com"/>
```

and a user browses through that `iframe`. Does Google see the request made from the server I'm hosting my site on, or from the user's router?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do NOT load content of iframe source from your server. You just pass that  code to the user browser then everything happens on client side. Therefore google will see client ip address and etc.

When one website is called through another domain whether iframe or not, browsers send current domain name to the next target (google.com in your case) with HTTP Referrer data. This is the only way of google.com to understand where the client request google from.

Details : [What is the HTTP Referer if the link is clicked in an <iframe>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468335/what-is-the-http-referer-if-the-link-is-clicked-in-an-iframe)